# View google chrome's cached pictures

Tags: google-chrome

How can I view the pictures that Google Chrome cached on websites?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This page contains all the cached urls

```
chrome://cache
```

Unfortunately to actually see the file you have to select everything on the page and paste it in this tool: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html

Comment: `chrome://cache` doesn't work for me. Neither does `chrome://view-http-cache`. I couldn't find anything about it. Probably something with my setup, or it was removed/changed.

Comment: chrome://cache was removed.

Comment: what about cached images?

Comment: This was removed. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=811956

Answer (score 31):

```
%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
```

paste this in your address bar and enter, you will get all the files

just rename the files extension into the extension which u r looking.

ie. open command prompt then

```
C:\>cd %UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
```

then

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache>ren *.* *.jpg
```

Comment: `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache>ren *.jpg *.""` seemed to undo the changes (remove all file extensions)

Answer (score 19):

Modified version from @dovidev as his version loads the image externally instead of reading the local cache.

1. Navigate to chrome://cache/
2. In the chrome top menu go to "View > Developer > Javascript Console"
3. In the console that opens paste the below and press enter

```js
var cached_anchors = $$('a');
document.body.innerHTML = '';
for (var i in cached_anchors) {
    var ca = cached_anchors[i];
    if(ca.href.search('.png') > -1 || ca.href.search('.gif') > -1 || ca.href.search('.jpg') > -1) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", ca.href);
        xhr.responseType = "document";
        xhr.onload = response;
        xhr.send();
    }
}

function response(e) {
  var hexdata = this.response.getElementsByTagName("pre")[2].innerHTML.split(/\r?\n/).slice(0,-1).map(e => e.split(/[\s:]+\s/)[1]).map(e => e.replace(/\s/g,'')).join('');
  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(hexdata.length/2);
  for (var x = 0; x < byteArray.length; x++){
      byteArray[x] = parseInt(hexdata.substr(x*2,2), 16);
  }
  var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```

Comment: My hero!!!!!!!!

Comment: As of 2018, chrome://cache/ is no longer reachable since Chrome 66. What's Plan B?

Answer (score 16):

This tool appears to serve your purposes: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

Comment: It works, but I don't see some elements that chrome loading from cache.

Answer (score 7):

You can make a bookmark with this as the url:

```
javascript:
var cached_anchors = $$('a');
for (var i in cached_anchors) {
    var ca = cached_anchors[i];
    if(ca.href.search('sprite') < 0 && ca.href.search('.png') > -1 || ca.href.search('.gif') > -1 || ca.href.search('.jpg') > -1) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = ca.innerHTML;
        a.target = '_blank';

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = ca.innerHTML;
        img.style.maxHeight = '100px';

        a.appendChild(img);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
    }
}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]);
void(0);
```

Then just go to chrome://cache and then click your bookmark and it'll show you all the images.

Comment: Could you explain it better?

Comment: chrome://cache no longer works